# How can I run a selenium test every 5 minutes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have created a Selenium test using the Firefox Addon. Now, I want to make it run every 5 mins. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it every 5 minutes, you will have to use export your test from IDE to be used in selenium-rc. For scheduling you can use [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) or cron.

Comment: +1 for Selenium RC. But using a CI tool in this case is a bit like using a nuclear plant to power a light bulb, no ? What about a cron ? Or a simple scheduler like quartz if software integration is needed ?

Comment: Agree with using Quartz or cron for scheduling. I have rephrased my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of javascript function or java's scheduler class ect..

please try to be specific so that you will get quick responses

cheers